# Java ME mobile emulator - отсутствует текст, отображающийся системными шрифтами

Tags: mobile, j2me, java, эмулятор, netbeans

Добрый вечер.

Бьюсь целый день, не могу понять, в чем проблема и куда копать.

Есть два компьютера: домашний и рабочий.На каждом из них стоит

Netbeans 7.3 + Java ME platform SDK 3.3 Preview

Версии одинаковые.

Запускаю Java ME mobile emulator (JavaMEPhone1) (и из netbeans, и отдельно)
Про приложение даже не пишу - уже в меню эмулятора на рабочем компе не отображаются тексты к иконкам меню. В приложении опытным путем обнаружил, что если брать из bitmap шрифт из Resources, и добавлять в Style к, например, Lable, то такой текст отображается. Не отображаются именно те тексты, которые используют Font.getSystemFont()

[На рабочем нет текстов](http://yadi.sk/d/cbM5RAuk4Z9ZO)

[На домашнем компе все в порядке](http://yadi.sk/d/KfQGkdtn4Z9fY)

В чем может быть проблема и куда стоит копать? У меня идеи кончились.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Господи, ну неужели еще есть те кто пишут под Java ME?

*Прости мя Господи за поминание имя Твое всуе...*

1. Проверьте кодировку текста на котором написаны ваши исходники, должно быть что-то типа ISO-8859-1
2. Возможно на рабочем компе отсутствуют какие-то шрифты, некоторые сисадмины грешат этим и не устанавливают полный комплект шрифтов на рабочие компы или устанавливают их урезанные версии

Вообще за давностью лет уже всего и не упомню отчего и почему. Скорее всего проблема в маппинге шрифтов.

Comment: Господи, ну неужели еще есть те кто пишут под Java ME? - это была первая мысль у меня в голове:)

Comment: Благодарю, завтра буду разбираться на работе со шрифтами. Все указывает в эту сторону.

Comment: Проблема решена. Для связи с рабочим компом я юзал MS Remote Desktop Connection Manager. Шрифт в эмуляторе начал отображаться, когда я включил (1) сглаживание шрифтов в rdcm. Сюрреализм.